# Why the histogram look different using two different breaks argument in R?

Tags: r, histogram, distribution

I want to plot the distribution of the datasets using the histogram in R. I tried using different arguments (default, Freedman-Diaconis, and Scott) to get the best representation. I consider using a log scale later, but first I want to know the raw distribution without any scaling. However, the results look different, why is that? The dataset I use can be downloaded from here [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vg0nb3p12fWXQRfazncccumhp2MEehQw/view?usp=sharing) or here [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j95gzgzp7renzrz/regression_coefficient_all_spots_binomial.csv?dl=0). The code I'm running are

```
hist(as.matrix(deviation_all_genes_all_spots), xlim = c(-(1*10^(4)), 10^(4.5)), breaks = 200)
```

result is [image]

```
hist(as.matrix(deviation_all_genes_all_spots), xlim = c(-(1*10^(4)), 10^(4.5)), breaks = "Scott")
```

Result is [image]

```
hist(as.matrix(deviation_all_genes_all_spots), xlim = c(-(1*10^(4)), 10^(4.5)), breaks="Freedman-Diaconis")
```

result is [image]

Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: The breaks are much smaller in the last plot. You can also check the underlying functions `nclass.scott()` and `class.FD()`

Comment: @Roman I have checked them and got the number of classes are 7518, 114767, and 28 for Scott, FD, and Sturges, respectively. However, I still do not get why the former two arguments only show the distribution of non-negative values?

Comment: are you sure? Have you checked the breaks like in the answer below? Try also to zoom in with suitable xaxis limits.

Comment: @Roman Yes, I am sure. I zoom in already, and it only started from 0 and positives.

Comment: Your dataset requires a user to request access on Google Drive. Please publish it somewhere where it can be accessed immediately.

Comment: @CasparV. I have updated it. Hopefully you can access it now.

Comment: From which column in the data do you want to plot the histogram? There is no column "eviation_all_genes_all_spots".

Comment: @cdalitz I want to plot the distribution of all values across all columns and rows.

Comment: The data you provide cannot be the data that you show in your plots. When I load the data into a varible *x* with `read.csv(..., header=T)`, convert the non-factorial columns into  a numeric vector with `y <- as.numeric(as.matrix(x[,-1]))`, then `range(y)` returns [-0.04622332,  0.08013825], and not something that goes into the ten thousands.

Comment: @MKHuda: Show us how you created `deviation_all_genes_all_spots` from the CSV. I see you're not new here, but please take the time to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and check out the answers to [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Histograms are very sensitive to the choice of cell break points. Even for the same (!) number of cells, the histogram can become considerably different by just a small shift of the cell borders. It is thus generally preferable to use kernel density estimators instead of histograms, because they do not depend on random cell border placement:

```
# increase n if you have a wide range of values
d <- density(as.matrix(deviation_all_genes_all_spots), n=512)
plot(d$x, d$y)
```

In your second and third call of `hist`, you ask for an automatic way to select the number of cells and the cell borders. Obviously, this results in more cells than in your first call with `breaks=200`. You can query the cells from the return value of `hist`, e.g.

```
h <- hist(as.matrix(deviation_all_genes_all_spots))
cat(srintf("number of cells = %i\n", length(h$mids))
```

Comment: That is true that the method will select the number of cells automatically. However, the issue is why it only shows non-negative value distribution, ignoring the negative values? The number of cells using the code you suggested is relatively low, only 34. The density is difficult to understand the distribution though, I have tried it.

Comment: Can you please make the data available, so that I can test it? The URL in the question requires a Google Drive account.

Comment: I have updated it. Hopefully, you can access it now.